# More efficient double For loop over 70k variables?

Tags: python, optimization

I have a long list of words in an array -- about 70k of them. I'm building a graph of all the words that are within some edit distance of the other words.

```
graph = dict()
for word in words:
    for target in words:
        if distance(word, target) == 1:
            if graph.get(word, 0) == 0:
                graph[word] = [target]
            else:
                graph[word].append(target)
```

In other words:

```
graph['sword'] = ['swore','sworn','word','swords',...]
```

etc.

We can assume that the function `distance` is optimized.

This loop takes a long time to run. Hours if I'm lucky, days if I'm not. When I'm done, I obviously save and pickle the file for later use, but if I want to update the graph with another word list, I'm stuck running this loop again.

Is there a package suitable for handling a case like this? Some way of speeding up the loop, or having some package magically turn this into C code so that it runs lickety split? I'm new to this world, so please inform me if there is a way, or if I'll have to take up knitting.

Comment: That's a classic O(n^2) algorithm.  I'd stock up on yarn.

Comment: @MarkRansom Love it. :-)

Comment: Perhaps you can think of some useful properties of the `distance` function that make it easy to ignore lots of possibilities at once?

Comment: Please add more details about your graph and the `distance` function!

Comment: You could try to find some way to leverage Numpy arrays to utilise the power of C loops. Although that'll still be slow since this is an O(n^2) algoriithm

Comment: You should be able to exploit the `distance` function as @KarlKnechtel said. Aside from improving your algorithm: you can use `for word, target in itertools.product(words, words)` to replace the nested `for`S, you can alias `graph.get()` into the local scope like so `get_word = graph.get; get_word(word, 0) == 0`, and for that matter you can call `graph.get()` just once each iteration and save the value to a local variable before testing the value and adding it to `graph[word]`.

Comment: Actually, preallocate `graph` like so `graph = {word: [] for word in words}` and then you don't need to test the value of `graph.get(word, 0)`, just `graph[word].append()` for either branch.

Comment: Any chance `len(words) > len(set(words))`? If so, consider either converting `words` to a `set()` or memoizing `distance()`.

Comment: There is a way to "turn this into C code" without writing C: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html. I suppose you could also add concurrency via `multiprocessing` or `threading`, depending on whether `distance()` is CPU or I/O bound.

Comment: I can see two obvious options
1. parallelise the whole thing with multiprocessing - dumb and simple.
2. You could use numba. This might require a restructure of your loop (e.g. preallocating a ``len(words) x len(words)`` binary array to store the result of every call to ``distance``). This could be used in combination with step 1, or you could use numba's own multiprocessing features. Numba will (I think) be far more effective if you can also apply numba to the ``distance`` function.